# Apache UIMA + Apache Solr Integration for Noun Phrase annotator

Tags: apache, solr, lucene, uima

I am working on Apache UIMA + Apache Solr integration. First I have integrated Apache UIMA with eclipse. I have implemented NOUN phrase annotator in eclipse and ran few examples of it.

It worked fine and giving accurate result by finding nouns in sentence.

Now I am trying to implement UIMA with Solr. I followed following link for the same:

https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrUIMA

I have exported working JAR file of eclipse project in apache solr lib directory and included other necessary jar files.

Here is my solrconfig xml changes :

```
            <lib dir="../../../contrib/uima/lib" />

            <lib dir="../../../contrib/uima/lucene-libs" />

            <lib dir="../../../dist/" regex="solr-uima-\d.*\.jar" />       

            <lib dir="C:\apache-uima\lib" />



            <requestHandler name="/update" class="solr.UpdateRequestHandler">

                            <lst name="defaults">

                              <str name="update.processor">uima</str>

                            </lst>

            </requestHandler>



            <updateRequestProcessorChain name="uima" default="true">

              <processor class="org.apache.solr.uima.processor.UIMAUpdateRequestProcessorFactory">

                            <lst name="uimaConfig">

                              <lst name="runtimeParameters">

                              </lst>

                              <str name="analysisEngine">/desc/NounPhraseAnnotator.xml</str>

                              <bool name="ignoreErrors">false</bool>

                              <str name="logField">id</str>

                              <lst name="analyzeFields">

                                            <bool name="merge">false</bool>

                                            <arr name="fields">

                                              <str>text</str>

                                            </arr>

                              </lst>

                              <lst name="fieldMappings">

                                            <lst name="type">

                                              <str name="name">org.apache.uima.tutorial.NounPhraseAnnotation</str>

                                              <lst name="mapping">

                                                            <str name="feature">nounText</str>

                                                            <str name="field">uimanounphrase</str>

                                              </lst>

                                            </lst>



                              </lst>

                            </lst>

              </processor>

              <processor class="solr.LogUpdateProcessorFactory" />

              <processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory" />

            </updateRequestProcessorChain>
```

Schema.xml changes:

```
            <field name="uimanounphrase" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" required="false"/>
```

Then I have indexed some documents and ran solr instance. But when I execute query, nouns are not coming in uimanounphrase field. Null values are showing up in that field.

Answer (score 0):

You have to generate the PEAR file first and install it. Once you do that, you can add an AE.xml to your solr config to make it work.

Step1: Generate PEAR file from your annotator implementation. You can use Eclipse to do that if you have UIMA plugin for Eclipse.

Step2: Install the PEAR file. You can use scripts provided in the apache-uima package(runPearInstaller.bat). You can also test if your pear file is working by running cvd.bat.

Step3: Create an annotator engine xml file (ex: OpenNLP_AE.xml) which you can integrate with solrconfig.xml

References: https://uima.apache.org/doc-uima-pears.html . This link has the pointers on how you can perform the above.

Hope this helps.